# How do I pass parameters to the batch file in this PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have syntax similar to the below in PowerShell:

```
param($1,$2,$3,$4)
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $1
$scriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("cmd /c $2 $3 $4")
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Where $2 is a .bat and $3 & $4 are arguments I want to pass to the executable. If I run it without arguments I can run the .bat but when I add in the arguments it fails. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: To provide further information, I am calling the above by running this in PowerShell:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F "powershellscript for the above" -1 "value" -2 "value" -3 "value" -4 "value"
```

Comment: "but when I add in the arguments it fails." - how do you add the arguments, and how does it fail (please share any errors thrown, in full)?

Comment: Added some more information about how I'm calling it. The error thrown is invalid batch file.

Comment: sounds like everything is working, except `cmd` on the remote machine might not be able to find the batch file on the remote machine - the argument you pass as `-2`, is it a fully rooted path? Does it have spaces in it? To verify that the local PowerShell bits are working, try replacing the `Invoke-Command` statement with `Write-Host "About to execute { $sriptblock } against $1"`

Comment: Ok thanks let me try and I'll confirm back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use local variables inside remote session, you must prefix them with `$Using:` [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-local-variables).

Try this:

```bsh
param($1,$2,$3,$4)
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $1
$scriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock({ cmd /c $Using:2 $Using:3 $Using:4 })
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```